# Why InputType "Phone" allows some special characters like N, #, etc

Tags: android, xml, android-inputtype

I've set the InpuType as "Phone" for my edittext at Xml. But it allows some characters like "N", "#", ".", Pause", "Wait", etc. Is it any country mobile number includes "N" in its mobile number, irrespective of the mobile number country code. If so, what are all the countries. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can add `digits="0123456789#+"` in XML and it will allow only these digits.

Answer (score 4):

To make sure your EditText only takes digits, you can do this,

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:digits="0123456789+" 
/>
```

I have been using it and never faced an issue inputting phone numbers.

Comment: Yes. I can restrict that by adding that digits or setting inputtype as "number". But i just want is there any country's mobile number contains "N" or"#" as number in it.

Comment: It seems to be going out of fashion, but some US companies still like to publish phone numbers like 1-800-FLOWERS.